# Problem extracting a numeric value from a string and save to a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am new to Python and posted my problem earlier on and received suggestion from others and still could not fix my problem.  I am re-posting my post with some modification, incorporated suggestions from others.  I am not only new to Python, but also have problems articulating my problems.

I want to convert all the prices from string to numeric, from example, “3K” to “3000” to maintain consistency in data analysis. At the moment, K means thousand and it is sufficient, no need to go into millions or billions.

This is done on Python data frame and I am still not familiar to iteration, list, and encounter errors that I do not understand.

a)  I could not convert string to float. "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"

b)  Then I decided to convert to string but I could not store it on the data frame as string. My output was empty cell.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re 

def regex_filter(val):
    new_price = val
    if val:
        price = ' '
        mo = re.search('\d+[kK]',val)
        if mo:
            price = str(price).replace('K','000')
            print("The New value is ",price)
            new_price = price
            return new_price
        else:
            return new_price
    else:
        return new_price


if __name__ == "__main__": 

    df = pd.read_csv('ProductID_price.csv', encoding='utf8')
    df['price'] = df['price'].apply(regex_filter)
```

INPUT

```
    product_id  product_name                        price
0   1           Mares XR Kevlar Diving Dry Suit     3K
1   2           Beuchat Abyss Dry Diving Dry Suit   2050    
2   3           Typhoon Scuba Dive Dry Suit     1.5K
3   4           Scubapro Evertech Drysuit Men       4,059.99
```

OUTPUT

```
    product_id  product_name                        price
0   1   Mares XR Kevlar Diving Dry Suit 
1   2   Beuchat Abyss Dry Diving Dry Suit           2050
2   3   Typhoon Scuba Dive Dry Suit 
3   4   Scubapro Evertech Drysuit Men               4,059.99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
def conv(s, conv_from="K", conv_to=1000):
    return s.mask(
        s.str.contains(f"\d+{conv_from}", na=False),
        pd.to_numeric(s.str.replace(conv_from,""), 
                      errors="coerce") * conv_to,
        errors="ignore")

# get rid of commas and spaces    
df["price"] = df["price"].str.replace(r"[\s,]", "")

df["price"] = df["price"].pipe(conv, "[Kk]", 10**3).pipe(conv, "[Mm]", 10**6)
```

Example:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
      price
0        3K
1     0.56M
2      2050
3      1.5K
4  4,059.99
```

solution:

```
In [97]: df["price"] = df["price"].str.replace(r"[\s,]", "")

In [98]: df["price"] = df["price"].pipe(conv, "[Kk]", 10**3).pipe(conv, "[Mm]", 10**6)
```

result:

```
In [99]: df
Out[99]:
     price
0     3000
1   560000
2     2050
3     1500
4  4059.99
```

Comment: I tested your codes on my Jupyter and I got this error message:

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2

Comment: My original codes have the same error message too.  Restarted my Jupyter and restarted my PC a few times and I still get the same error message.

Comment: @Tony, are you sure you've tested __my__ code? This error is usually thrown by the `pd.read_*` methods - i don't have it in my code

Comment: Not sure how to proceed or fix it.

Comment: I re-run my original code and I got the same message.  I am thinking of uninstalling my jupyter and the re-installing.

Comment: @Tony, which line of my code produces mentioned error?

Comment: This line : df = pd.read_csv('ProductID_price.csv', encoding='utf8')

Comment: @Tony, which line of __my__ code produces mentioned error?  ;-)

Comment: Here is the full error message: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2

Comment: I ran a totally different code and am able to read a different file. It could be that my file is corrupted.

Comment: MaxU, I am just giving you a feedback, not accusing you of anything. I am kind of loss.

Comment: I have a look at the file and it is corrupted. I am fixing it now.

Comment: Thanks MaxU.  It is the file and it is working after I corrected the file. I am going to test your code again and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Hi MaxU, thanks for the codes. It is working very well.  Could you explain your codes so that I can reuse your codes for something else.? 
For example, I have a string of alphanumeric and I want to take the numbers (fifty percent discount of $200 and I just want 200) and if there are two or more numbers (between 100 and 200), I would take the highest number as the final answer. Would you be able to help?